# Direct upload to S3 from NAS

Tags: amazon-s3, nas

I'm trying to set up an S3 backup for my company's NAS (a QNAP TS-EC879U-RD), and I'm having some trouble. The NAS device itself has a much faster network connection than the computer that I'm using to upload (10Gb/s vs 1Gb/s), but it seems like every tool I explore has to move data through my computer first. I'm sure there must be a way to bypass this bottleneck, but I can't imagine what it is. Any help pointing me in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this would be to have the NAS itself run the upload software. Otherwise, the data MUST be read from the NAS into your PC and then sent via the upload software to S3.

Think about it this way: What you're asking for is software that can see what files are on the NAS, then *tell the NAS* to upload the files through its network connection. If you could do this without having to install software on the NAS, then any software running on your PC (i.e., a virus) could tell the NAS to upload its data to some hacker's servers.

As such, either you need to have the software running on the NAS itself, which can then directly upload data to S3, or the upload software will need to suck the data from the NAS into your PC and then upload it to S3.